# flutter simple text example

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am a beginner in flutter android development. While I was learning I found a simple helloworld example.

In the main class,

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget
{
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 // TODO: implement build
 return MaterialApp(home: Text('Helloworld!'),);
}
```

after passing Helloworld! text, they provide a `,`. They do not provide any arguments. But still, the app displays helloworld.

What is the need for that coma, if there is not any other argument?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether that comma is there or not( if you don't use another property ) but if you want to use another property then you need to put comma there

Answer (score 1):

*A comma is used to separate parameters of a function or method but is optional. If you use comma but do not pass other values to other parameters, it's ignored.*

Answer (score 1):

you take Text() in home:, and home has many arguments so that comma is added but comma is not required when you have only one argument,comma is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually this is called ***trailing comma***, and according to flutter guidelines,

> The guideline for adding a ***trailing comma*** is simple: Always add a trailing comma at the end of a parameter list in functions, methods, and constructors where you care about keeping the formatting you crafted. This helps the automatic formatter to insert an appropriate amount of line breaks for Flutter-style code.

Read more [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/formatting#automatically-formatting-code-with-the-flutter-command)